# Typescript - String to type

Tags: typescript, reflection

I have a class `Message` representing some data. Every message share the same header. However, depending on the type of message, they have different payloads. For example:

```
class Message {
  serial: string
  length: number
}

class LKMessage extends Message {}

class UDMessage extends Message {
  location: Location
}
```

The problem here is that I don't know the message type. The user just says "post a message", and sends the type along with the data.
I could potentially create a different post function for every type of message, but I would write the same code a lot.

I tried something like this:

```
interface MessagePayload {}

interface LKMessagePayload extends MessagePayload {}

interface UDMessagePayload extends MessagePayload {
  location: Location
}

class Message<T extends MessagePayload> {
  serial: string
  length: number
  payload: T
}
```

The problem is instantiation: the user sends the type as a `string`, so I can't just write `new Message<type>(data)`.
I thought of using reflection, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field called `type` and set it to a unique string in each type. Then you will know what class to use.

```
class Message {
    type: string = "base"
    serial: string
    length: number
}

class LKMessage extends Message {
    type: "LK" = "LK"
}

class UDMessage extends Message {
    type: "UD" = "UD"
    location: Location
}
```

So when you are trying to read messages your code would do something like

```
let message: Message = readSomeMessageIn()

if (message.type === "UD") {
    const typedMessage: UDMessage = message as UDMessage;


} else if (message.type === "LK") {
    const typedMessage: LKMessage = message as LKMessage;
}
```

Comment: How exactly would I use that code? I don't get how that would help

Comment: @HillelSAAL i edited in some code to show how to use it

Comment: Now I get what you mean. The problem is that I have ~50 types of messages, so it would be a pretty long switch. That's why I'd like to do it using a type reflection

Comment: Typescript typing has no runtime component. The types do not exist at runtime, so reflection cannot work. That is the purpose of the `type` field. To give something that can be evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your help